# Indentation error in Python (in Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x

can someone please tell me how to solve this error?
This function is supposed to return the lesser of two given numbers if both numbers are even, but returns the greater if one or both numbers are odd
I know there is a simple way to write, but this is my way and I'm curious to know why I got this error

[image: Click to see the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `if` is indented one space **more** than the `else` it's supposed to correspond to (and the other if-elses). Remove a space before it, and you should be OK.

Comment: Oh my god, I was scratching my head for a couple of hours for this :)) ... Thanks a lot